# RxJava 2 concurrency- how to zip on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, rx-java

How can we observe there results on the current/initial thread? On android we can use `observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` but how to do this in case of a simple application eg. for a server side application.

```
  public void testParallelZip() throws InterruptedException {

    Maybe.zip(
            getStrings("first", 2000, "One", "Two").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            getStrings("second", 1000, "Three", "Four").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            getStrings("third", 1000, "Five", "Six").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            mergeStringLists())
          //  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) Where to observe
            .subscribe(strings -> {
                        System.out.println("result on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println(strings);
                    },
                    throwable -> System.out.println("oops"),
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed "));

    System.out.println("exit");
}

private static Maybe<List<String>> getStrings(String tag, int delay, final String str1, final String str2) {
    return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {
        sleep(tag, delay);
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add(str1);
        strings.add(str2);
        return strings;
    });
}

private static void sleep(String tag, int time) {
    try {
        System.out.println(">Tag " + tag + " running on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(time);
        System.out.println("Tag " + tag + " running on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Function3<List<String>, List<String>, List<String>, List<String>> mergeStringLists() {
    return (strings, strings2, strings3) -> {
        System.out.println("merging in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (String s : strings2) {
            strings.add(s);
        }

        for (String s : strings3) {
            strings.add(s);
        }

        return strings;
    };
}
```

I have tried [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/370) i.e. use Schedulers.from() but it requires calling `tasks.take().run()` manually. May be there is a better way?

```
 tasks = LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()

 Maybe.zip(
            getStrings("first", 2000, "One", "Two").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            getStrings("second", 1000, "Three", "Four").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            getStrings("third", 1000, "Five", "Six").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
            mergeStringLists())
     .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executor { runnable -> 
           tasks.add(runnable) }))
     .subscribe(strings -> {
                        System.out.println("result on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println(strings);
                    },
                    throwable -> System.out.println("oops"),
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed "));

 tasks.take().run()
```

Comment: You'll have to be synchronous again. Just block. `obs.toBlocking().forEach(...)`

Comment: That would work but I don't want it to be blocking.

Comment: If your main thread is not part of an even loop (like the Android main thread), you haven't any other choose. If you don't block, you're thread will be terminated. How can it be resumed afterwards?

Comment: the example using `Schedulers.from()` and `LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>` works but tbh I don't fully understand how. We need to call `tasks.take().run()` .. which I guess resumes the original thread.